# how to deploy flask app that uses socket communication on nginx, ubuntu bare metal

Tags: python, ubuntu, nginx, flask, websocket

Hi I want to deploy flask api that uses socket io to pass data frame to another server. I need to deploy this application in prod system.

I am using nginx
I tried using gunicorn but it is breaking in google oauth.

I also considered daphne , but only supports django ?!

Comment: StackOverflow is best suited to targeted, specific questions about specific code. Vague questions about things that somehow don't work in unseen code and about suggestions for alternative technology don't work so well on this platform.